# How to recover deleted file if it is still opened by some process?

Tags: linux, file-recovery

```
$ cat important_file > /dev/null &
[1] 9711
$ rm important_file 
$ killall -STOP cat

[1]+  Stopped                 cat important_file > /tmp/p
$ ls -l /proc/`pidof cat`/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 vi vi 64 May 13 20:32 0 -> /dev/pts/29
l-wx------ 1 vi vi 64 May 13 20:32 1 -> /tmp/p
lrwx------ 1 vi vi 64 May 13 20:32 2 -> /dev/pts/29
lr-x------ 1 vi vi 64 May 13 20:32 3 -> /home/vi/important_file (deleted)
```

How to recover this `important_file`?

I tried something like

```
injcode -m dup2 -ofd=3 -ofilename=/tmp/recovered_file -oflags=O_CREAT $PID_OF_CAT
```

but it does nothing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If /home is NFS, there will be a .nfsNNNNNNNNNN file in /home/vi that you can access/copy.  If home is a local filesystem, you should be able to do the same thing via the /proc/PID/fd/3 link:

```
cp /proc/PID/fd/3 /tmp/recovered_file
```

If you want to actually undelete the file, here's a [blog post](http://glandium.org/blog/?p=87) on the subject.

Comment: OK, I was confused by that `readlink /proc/13381/fd/3` -> "/home/vi/important_file (deleted)" and `/home/vi/important_file\ \(deleted\)` obviously does not exist.

Comment: lmao! I love you!  I was examining a particular vmlinux in gdb for a _very_ particular stack trace for a mysterious race condition, forgot about that and rebuilt the kernel with different .config options.

Answer (score 37):

... better than copying at a given time (and gathering only that time's snapshot of the file's content) is to "`tail -f`" that file into a new file:

> `tail -c +0 -f /proc/PIDofProgram>/fd/# > /new/path/to/file`

(thanks to tail's cautious programmers, that will even work with binary output.)

During its runtime, the `tail -f` itself keeps the file open, safely preventing it from being purged off disk when the original program ends. Thus, don't stop the `tail -f` immediately after your original program ends - check the tail'ed `/new/path/to/file` first whether it *is* what you want. If it isn't (or is unsatisfying for any other reason), you can copy the original file again, but this time *after* all writing to it has finished by "Program" and from the still-running `tail -f`'s  /proc/PIDoftail/fd/ directory.

Comment: What about creating a hardlink to /proc/PIDofProgram>/fd/# ?

Comment: @becko `Invalid cross-device link`.

Answer (score 18):

Use lsof to find the inode number, and debugfs to recreate a hard link to it. For example:

```
# lsof -p 12345 | grep /var/log/messages
syslogd 12345 root    3w   REG                8,3    3000    987654 /var/log/messages (deleted)
# mount | grep var
/dev/sda2 on /var type ext3 (rw)
# debugfs -w /dev/sda2
debugfs: cd log
debugfs: ln <987654> tmp
debugfs: mi tmp
                      Mode    [0100600] 
                   User ID    [0] 
                  Group ID    [0] 
                      Size    [3181271] 
             Creation time    [1375916400] 
         Modification time    [1375916322] 
               Access time    [1375939901]
             Deletion time    [9601027] 0
                Link count    [0] 1
               Block count    [6232] 
                File flags    [0x0] 
...snip...
debugfs:  q
# mv /var/log/tmp /var/log/messages
# ls -al /var/log/messages
-rw------- 0 root root 3301 Aug  8 10:10 /var/log/messages
```

---

Before you complain, I faked the above transcript as I don't have a deleted file to hand right now ;-)

I use `mi` to reset the delete time and link count to sensible values (0 and 1 respectively), but it doesn't work properly - you can see the link count remains at zero in `ls`. I think the kernel might be caching the inode data. You should probably fsck at the earliest opportunity after using debugfs, to be on the safe side.

In my experience, you should create the link using a temporary file name and then rename to the proper name. Linking it directly to the original file name seems to cause directory corruption. YMMV!

- http://glandium.org/blog/?p=87
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-ext3-ext4-deleted-files-recovery-howto.html

Comment: Why exactly are you suggesting this if it doesn't really work properly and causes system damage?  I think you should have a more vivid disclaimer within the answer that this is simply a WiP, and should not really be tried in production.

Answer (score 4):

You can just `cp` the file, i.e:

```
cp /proc/<pid>/fd/<fdno> /new/path/to/file
```

Of course, if the file is still being modified, you'll run into trouble with this approach.

Comment: On my system (Xubuntu 18.04.2), `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fdno>`  is just an orphaned symbolic link: `cp: cannot open '/proc/<pid>/fd/<fdno>' for reading: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

If your file is still being written to (so you cant use `cp`), and you're not using `ext` (so you cant use `debugfs`) here's an agnostic way of doing it.

Once you find the process using `ps aux | grep` or however, and you've double checked the removed filename via `lsof -p $pid -a -d $fd` you can use the following spawn a new process whose sole job is to revive it:

```bash
(tail -f -n +1 --pid $pid /proc/$pid/fd/$fd) >$file </dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The weird wrapping is just to [safeguard against `HUP`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26912302/2518317), so feel free to not use it or swap it out for `nohup`

Comment: I remember sometimes `/proc/.../fd/...` being just unopenable for deleted files. I don't remember details like FS or original file open mode.

Comment: I had a long-running nohupped script piping into gzip and I stupidly renamed a file to where it was going yesterday. Doing this it successfully pulled the file back, but maybe it was because it's fd1 specifically and gzip wasnt killed